# Trying to grab suburb names from Wikipedia with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am just starting out with beautiful soup and trying to extract Melbourne's suburbs from Wikipedia. [Here is the link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Melbourne_suburbs)

The suburb names are all linked text meaning I have to grab them from an a href tag, I can't figure out how to do this.

Here is what I've tried:

```
suburb_names = soup_suburb_list.find_all('a', href=True)
```

But this just returns ALL the href tags on the page, I can't figure out how to differentiate the hrefs so the scraper only fetches the names of suburbs.

I'd be grateful for any insights :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. Let me know if you have any questions.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

wikipedia = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Melbourne_suburbs')

soup = BeautifulSoup(wikipedia.content, 'html.parser')

suburbs_containers = soup.select(".mw-parser-output > ul")
#.mw-parser-output is the class of the div that contains the main
#content of the page. This selects <ul> elements with .mw-parser-output as
#their parent

suburbs = []

for container in suburbs_containers: #iterates through the groups of suburbs
    suburb_list = container.find_all('a') #finds all anchors within a group
    for suburb in suburb_list: #iterates through these suburbs
        suburbs.append(suburb.text) #appends the names of the suburbs to the
                                    #main list of suburbs


print(suburbs)
```

Code explanation:

Looking through the Wikipedia page, it seemed that a div with the class `.mw-parser-output` contained the middle part of the page, without the sidebar.

That already eliminates most of the useless anchors, and since the names of suburbs are in  elements that are direct children of `.mw-parser-output`, this selects just those ul elements.

Note that there are other ul elements that are NOT direct children, and don't contain just suburb names, like in the page summary, so using `soup.find_all('ul')` would not work here.

After the ul elements are found, just search for anchors within them and you have your list.

Comment: Thank you so much. Question: how would I know to use ".mw-parser-output > ul" in the future. This seems to have eliminated all the extraneous content from the webpage and only captured what I want, which is great, but don't understand how!

Comment: I hope this is clear. Please let me know if you need me to elaborate on anything else.